# Quad Tree Implementation Operator++

Tags: quadtree

I was wondering how you can implement an operator++ for a quad tree. I know that I have to go to the farthest child of the tree and then go to right.But not sure how to though. Any help would be appreciated. Thank You!

Comment: What is the meaning of ++ on a quadtree?

Comment: @harold so the meaning of ++, I would like to create an increment function in a quad tree so I can move along the tree

Comment: Do you mean an iterator to fetch all tree nodes one by one in some specific order, possibly with a syntax of a `for` loop in C language...?

Comment: So I would like to iterate through the entire tree node in a specific height oder